# why when i use formdata for multi checkbox the page stopped for debug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

i try to design a page with multi checkbox or multi radio

i use it to send the request to php page

i use:

in html : Form,POST,input:checkbox

in Javascript : function, formdata, for, case, swich, search, text, tel, url, password, datetime, date, month, week, file,checkbox ,radio ,text, password, ....elc

when i check one or more checkbox the page stopped

i dont know why

if any one can help me

```
<form method="POST" id="section" name="section" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputName2">go</label>
            <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="age[]" value="1" type="checkbox">15-20
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="age[]" value="2" type="checkbox">20-30
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="age[]" value="3" type="checkbox">30-....
            </label>
        </div>
    <hr>
            <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="tall[]" value="1" type="checkbox">100-120
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="tall[]" value="2" type="checkbox">121-140
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="tall[]" value="3" type="checkbox">141-150
            </label>
        </div>
    <hr>
</div>
        <div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputName2">ADD</label>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" name="ADD" id="add" value="ADD" onclick="AjaxPost('section');" type="button">
     </div>
    <input name="req" value="https://localhost/form.php" type="hidden">
     </form>
```

and the java script function is:

```
    function AjaxPost(rowid) {
var formData = new FormData();
var strSubmitContent = '';
document.getElementById(rowid).className="submit";
var url=document.forms[rowid].req.value;
var strSubmitContent = '';
var formElem;
var strLastElemName = '';
var docForm=document.forms[rowid];
for (i = 0; i < docForm.elements.length; i++) {
    formElem = docForm.elements[i];
    switch (formElem.type) {
        case 'hidden':
            formData.append(formElem.name,escape(formElem.value));
        break;
        case 'search':
        case 'text':
        case 'tel':
        case 'url':
        case 'password':
        case 'datetime':
        case 'date':
        case 'month':
        case 'week':
        case 'time':
        case 'datetime-local':
        case 'number':
        case 'range':
        case 'color':
        case 'textarea':
        case 'select-one':
            formData.append(formElem.name,escape(formElem.value));
        break;
        case 'email':
                var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
                if(re.test(formElem.value) == false){
                    err_or +="wrong EMail";
                }else {
                    formData.append(formElem.name,escape(formElem.value));
                }
        break;
        case 'submit':
            formData.append(formElem.name,escape(formElem.value));
        break;
        case 'image':
            formData.append(formElem.name,escape(formElem.value));
        break;
        case 'reset':
            formData.append(formElem.name,escape(formElem.value));
        break;
        case 'button':
            formData.append(formElem.name,escape(formElem.value));
        break;
        case 'optgroup':
            formData.append(formElem.name,escape(formElem.value));
        break;
        case 'radio':
            if (formElem.checked) {
                formData.append(formElem.name,escape(formElem.value));
            }
        break;
        case 'file':
            if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob){
                var fileSelect = document.getElementById(formElem.name);
                var files = fileSelect.files;
                var c = files.length;
                for(var i = 0; i<=c ; i++){
                    formData.append(formElem.name,files[i]);
                }
            }
        break;
        case 'checkbox':
    //  check_box(formElem);
    var dmfck=$(this).prop('checked', true);
    alert(dmfck.name);
    //if (formElem.checked == true) {
    //alert("amer");    
        //alert(formElem.name);
//      var checked_name=formElem.name;
        //formData.append(formElem.name,formElem.value);
    //}
        break;

    }
}
return;
$( "#results" ).empty();
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
    var res="<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\"><br />" + data + "</div>";
    $( "#results" ).append( res + " " );
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

}

Comment: In my opinion you should just do `var formData = new FormData(this.form)` and sort it out on the server. Seems like you're complicating things a lot with the strange switches, regex'es and appending espaced strings and each file in a loop etc?

Comment: thanks you very much but when i use another form element it stopped again